How to Escape Reserved Words in SQL Queries with R2DBC for SQL Server?
I'm working with a Spring Webflux application and using R2DBC to connect to a SQL Server database. I've encountered an issue when trying to perform a query that includes a reserved word as a column name. The column in question is named key, which is known to be a reserved word in SQL Server. Here's the query I'm trying to execute using Spring Data's @Query annotation:
@Query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE key = :key AND id = : id")

However, when I run this, I encounter the following error:

Caused by: io.r2dbc.mssql.ExceptionFactory$MssqlBadGrammarException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'key'.

Understanding that key is a reserved word, I attempted to escape it in various ways:

Using square brackets: SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE [key] = :key AND id = : id
Using double quotes: SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE "key" = :key AND id = :id
Using backticks: SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE `key` = :key AND id = :id

Unfortunately, none of these attempts have resolved the issue. It seems like there's something specific to R2DBC's handling of SQL queries that's causing the problem.
Has anyone successfully worked around this issue with R2DBC and SQL Server? How can you include a reserved word in your query without encountering a syntax error? Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated.

[key] should work, what error are you getting?

Caused by: io.r2dbc.mssql.ExceptionFactory$MssqlBadGrammarException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'key'.

And my @Query is like
@Query(SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE [key] = :key AND id = : id)

Using [key] works perfectly within SQL Server; however, the issue arises within the application, leading me to believe it's related to R2dbcRepository.

What does the parameter :key turn into on the wire? Could that be causing an issue?

What if you add: ,   nativeQuery = true to the query call

It's only and String, like [key] = Test

It's nativeQuery avaliable on WebFlux?

I don't know, you're sitting on the code =)

Shot in the dark: Check you code to see if you possibly have the same (or a similar) query defined in more than one place. If that's not it, try using the Query Profiler to capture that actual SQL that is being passed to the server for execution.

Perhaps, as a side note, you should be aiming to not use object names that are reserved key words. Unfortunately there are applications that handle such values poorly, so if you avoid the usage, you avoid the problem.

The code should not be generating [key] = Test, it should be passing through parameters properly. Is R2DBC actually capable of using parameterized queries? SQL Server uses @key not :key, not sure why you think that would work.

@Charlieface i think JPA "thing" does some magic rewriting and it uses own syntax for no reason whatsoever
